# Creating a timeline based on years in R

Tags: r, timeline

I am fairly new to coding with R. I am working with relatively easy data just a large amount of it. I am trying to create a timeline based on the years these species of whale were sighted. So I just have two variables (year and species) and 151 observations. There are a total of 25 species to plot on this time line and I have provided a small example of my data below.

```
year       species
1792    Megaptera novaeangliae
1792    Physeter macrocephalus
1793    Physeter macrocephalus
1832    Physeter macrocephalus
1833    Physeter macrocephalus
```

I have tried creating the timeline using timelineS and timelineG as well as vistime. TimelineG gets close to creating what I want but it does not seem to plot anything. The code is as follows:

`timelineG(t8, start="year", end="year", names="species")`

[timelineG results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBKdz.png)

I am just kind of stuck. I do have the month and day that the species were sighted so I can add that back if needed. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or like this using [timelineg](/questions/tagged/timelineg),

```
dta <- data.frame(species = c('Megaptera novaeangliae','Physeter macrocephalus',
                              'Physeter macrocephalus','Physeter macrocephalus',
                              'Physeter macrocephalus'),
                  year = c(1792,1792,1793,1832,1833))

#str(dta)
dta$year <- as.Date(ISOdate(dta$year, 1, 1)) # assuming beginning of year for year 
# str(dta)


timelineS(dta, main = "BGoodwin's species example")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An example with `ggplot`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~year,                 ~species,
        1792L, "Megaptera novaeangliae",
        1792L, "Physeter macrocephalus",
        1793L, "Physeter macrocephalus",
        1832L, "Physeter macrocephalus",
        1833L,  "Physeter macrocephalu"
        )

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = species)) +
  geom_point()
```

Or with the `timelineG` function:

```
library(timelineS)
df %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(year),
            end = max(year)) %>% 
  timelineG(start = "start", end = "end", names = "species")
```

Comment: AH! Yes! I was making this was more complicated then it should have been. This will work perfectly for what I am trying to show. Thank you!!!

Comment: @BGoodwin you're welcome! I updated my answer to also provide a solution using the `timelineG` function